# How can I plot data to a “best fit” cos² graph in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I’m currently a Physics student and for several weeks have been compiling data related to ‘Quantum Entanglement’. I’ve now got to a point where I have to plot my data (which should resemble a cos² graph - and does) to a sort of “best fit” cos² graph. The lab script says the following:

> A more precise determination of the visibility V (this is basically how 'clean' the data is) follows from the best fit to the measured data using the function:
>
> f(b) = A/2[1-Vsin(b-b(center)/P)]

Granted this probably doesn’t mean much out of context, but essentially A is the amplitude, b is an angle and P is the periodicity. Hence this is also a “wave” like the experimental data I have found.

From this I understand, as previously mentioned, I am making a “best fit” curve. However, I have been told that this isn’t possible with Excel and that the best approach is Matlab.

I know intermediate JavaScript but do not know Matlab and was hoping for some direction.

Is there a tutorial I can read for this? Is it possible for someone to go through it with me? I really have no idea what it entails, so any feed back would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What parameters do you want to find? A,b,P - or are there others?

Comment: Why is it not possible with Excel? Seems doable to me.

Comment: V i believe, as that is what i was also doing experimentally (tells you how clear the signal is basically, as when you minimise you would expect it to be 0). Not sure my lecturer said 'excel can't really data fit anything.

Answer (score 4):

### Initial steps

I guess we should begin by getting a representation in Matlab of the function that you're trying to model. A direct translation of your formula looks like this:

```
function y = targetfunction(A,V,P,bc,b)
    y = (A/2) * (1 - V * sin((b-bc) / P));
end
```

### Getting hold of the data

My next step is going to be to generate some data to work with (you'll use your own data, naturally). So here's a function that generates some noisy data. Notice that I've supplied some values for the parameters.

```
function [y b] = generateData(npoints,noise)

    A  = 2;
    V  = 1;
    P  = 0.7;
    bc = 0;

    b = 2 * pi * rand(npoints,1);

    y = targetfunction(A,V,P,bc,b) + noise * randn(npoints,1);

end
```

The function `rand` generates random points on the interval `[0,1]`, and I multiplied those by `2*pi` to get points randomly on the interval `[0, 2*pi]`. I then applied the target function at those points, and added a bit of noise (the function `randn` generates normally distributed random variables).

### Fitting parameters

The most complicated function is the one that fits a model to your data. For this I use the function `fminunc`, which does unconstrained minimization. The routine looks like this:

```
function [A V P bc] = bestfit(y,b)

    x0(1) = 1;   %# A
    x0(2) = 1;   %# V
    x0(3) = 0.5; %# P
    x0(4) = 0;   %# bc

    f = @(x) norm(y - targetfunction(x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),b));

    x = fminunc(f,x0);

    A  = x(1);
    V  = x(2);
    P  = x(3);
    bc = x(4);

end
```

Let's go through line by line. First, I define the function `f` that I want to minimize. This isn't too hard. To minimize a function in Matlab, it needs to take a single vector as a parameter. Therefore we have to pack our four parameters into a vector, which I do in the first four lines. I used values that are close, but not the same, as the ones that I used to generate the data.

Then I define the function I want to minimize. It takes a single argument `x`, which it unpacks and feeds to the `targetfunction`, along with the points `b` in our dataset. Hopefully these are close to `y`. We measure how far they are from `y` by subtracting from `y` and applying the function `norm`, which squares every component, adds them up and takes the square root (i.e. it computes the root mean square error).

Then I call `fminunc` with our function to be minimized, and the initial guess for the parameters. This uses an internal routine to find the closest match for each of the parameters, and returns them in the vector `x`.

Finally, I unpack the parameters from the vector `x`.

### Putting it all together

We now have all the components we need, so we just want one final function to tie them together. Here it is:

```
function master

    %# Generate some data (you should read in your own data here)
    [f b] = generateData(1000,1);

    %# Find the best fitting parameters
    [A V P bc] = bestfit(f,b);

    %# Print them to the screen
    fprintf('A = %f\n',A)
    fprintf('V = %f\n',V)
    fprintf('P = %f\n',P)
    fprintf('bc = %f\n',bc)

    %# Make plots of the data and the function we have fitted
    plot(b,f,'.');
    hold on
    plot(sort(b),targetfunction(A,V,P,bc,sort(b)),'r','LineWidth',2)

end
```

If I run this function, I see this being printed to the screen:

```
>> master

Local minimum found.

Optimization completed because the size of the gradient is less than
the default value of the function tolerance.

A = 1.991727
V = 0.979819
P = 0.695265
bc = 0.067431
```

And the following plot appears:

[image]

That fit looks good enough to me. Let me know if you have any questions about anything I've done here.

Comment: Thanks mate! That was amazing of you to go through all that, i havent put it into practice yet, but will be tomorrow. Will let you know how i get on, or if all goes well, the results.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, i've been fitting my data and it seems to work perfectly. I have to playing around with my P value for each set and doesn't appear to follow any sort of consistency, do you know why that might be? (all of my data sets share the same shape however vary in amplitude etc). Going to try and write a function now to find the error on my best fits.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit surprised as you mention f(a) and your function does not contain an a, but in general, suppose you want to plot f(x) = cos(x)^2

First determine for which values of x you want to make a plot, for example

```
xmin = 0;
stepsize = 1/100;
xmax = 6.5;
x = xmin:stepsize:xmax;
y = cos(x).^2;
plot(x,y)
```

However, note that this approach works just as well in excel, you just have to do some work to get your x values and function in the right cells.

Comment: Sorry, you are 100% correct, the function should also be depending on b. That was me messing up as i was flustered at the time. I think the idea is that i have to solve that function for V and plot each point against my experimental data (where i was also trying to find V), in a sense creating a sort of curve of best fit. Does what you have put above still apply? Thanks a lot for the help guys! ill try upload the part from the manual..

Regards